# A NumberPicker inside a ViewPager kills the horizontal swipe

Tags: android, android-viewpager, swipe, numberpicker

I have been working with a ViewPager for a long time and this morning, I have tried to include a NumberPicker inside the ViewPager.

The big problem I facing is that when trying to swipe the viewpager, it works everywhere except over the NumberPicker.

I really don't understand this behaviour!

For instance a ListView is fine, the horizontal swipe is processed by the ViewPager and the vertical one by the List.
I was expecting the same with a NumberPicker. No reason that the NumberPicket process the horizontal swipe

The code is quite trivial, I post here:

```
    ViewPager mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    if (mPager != null) 
        mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    ()...
class TabsAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        public TabsAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return TITLES.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return new FragmentAccueil();
            case 1:
                return new FragmentRecherche();
            case 2:
                return new FragmentFav();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            if (position == 0)
                try {
                    return TITLES[position]+" "+a.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                            a.getPackageName(), 0).versionName;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    return TITLES[position];
                }
            else
                return TITLES[position];
        }
    }
```

and the Fragment layout contains a NumberPicker:

```
   <NumberPicker
        android:id="@+id/numberPicker1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Comment: The fragment's layout contains **only** a `NumberPicker` or there are other widgets?

Comment: There are other widgets. The horizontal scroll on other widget is fine, the problem occurs only on NumberPicker. I guess that the issue is coming from the NumberPicker that "eats" the touch event and does not forward it to ViewPager

Comment: Can you add the complete layout file where you use this `NumberPicker`?

Comment: Problem also osccurs with a numberpicker only, so I guess the layout is irrelevant, but just in case: http://pastebin.com/xyVWEugA

Comment: Yes, the layout file was useless. I think the problem is the `EditText` used by the `NumberPicker` which steals the focus and the touch events when clicked. Unfortunately I don't know how you could overcome this, maybe by intercepting events at the level of the `ViewPager` or the `NumberPicker` itself.

Comment: You are right. but I have really no knowledge how to separate the horizontal and vertical motion, se the numberpicker keeps only vertical one and dispatch horizontal to viewpager

Comment: @Waza_Be you got the solution for this problem ??

Answer (score 2):

Create a custom ViewPager by extending it and implement dispatchTouchEvent.

We start tracking the touch ( with the pixel positions on sceen ) in `ACTION_DOWN`. When we see that it's a horizontal swipe, we do not call `super.dispatchTouchEvent( event )` - which would do the default onTouch routing and make the NumberPicker consume the horizontal swipe too - but call `onTouchEvent( event )` instead in `ACTION_MOVE` and also in `ACTION_UP`.

```
public class MyViewPager extends ViewPager {

private float mLastX;
private float mLastY;
private final int mTouchSlop = ViewConfiguration.get( getContext() ).getScaledTouchSlop();
private float mStartX;

public MyViewPager( Context context ) {
    super( context );
}

public MyViewPager( Context context, AttributeSet attrs ) {
    super( context, attrs );
}

@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent( MotionEvent event ) {
    switch( event.getAction() ) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            mLastX = event.getX();
            mLastY = event.getY();
            mStartX = event.getX();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            onTouchEvent( event );
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            float x = event.getX();
            float y = event.getY();

            float xDelta = x - mLastX;
            float xDeltaAbs = Math.abs( xDelta );
            float yDeltaAbs = Math.abs( y - mLastY );

            float xDeltaTotal = x - mStartX;
            if( Math.abs( xDeltaTotal ) > mTouchSlop )
                if( xDeltaAbs > yDeltaAbs )
                    return onTouchEvent( event );
    }

    return super.dispatchTouchEvent( event );
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

I know this is super old but it is still the first search result so I thought I'd answer it for future visitors.

The problem is indeed the EditText inside the NumberPicker. This swipe blocking also happens if you use any other EditText inside your ViewPager.

To fix that you have to programmatically disable horizontal scrolling for the EditText (doing it in XML doesn't work, because Android >_<).

First find android's internal id for NumberPicker's EditText and then set its horizontal scrolling to false:

```
int editTextId = Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier(
    "numberpicker_input", "id", "android");
((EditText) numberPicker.findViewById(editTextId)
    ).setHorizontallyScrolling(false);
```